# How does Nike's website do this Flash effect when the user selects a choice

Tags: web, flash

I was wondering how [does Nike website make the change](http://nikeid.nike.com/nikeid/?sitesrc=uslp) you can see when selecting a color or a sole. At first I thought they were only using images and when the user picked a color you just replaced that part, but when I selected a different sole I noticed it didn't changed like an image it looked a bit more as if it was being rendered. Does anybody happens to know how this is made? Or where can I get further info about making this effect :)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know for sure, but my guess would be that they're using a rendering service similar to that provided by [Adobe's Scene7](http://www.scene7.com/).

It's a product that is used to colorize/customize a base product image based on user choices.

If you're interested in using the service, I'd suggest signing up for their weekly webinar. I attended one a while back and was very impressed with their offering. They showed the Converse site (which had functionality almost identical functionality to the Nike site) as a demo.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of these tools are built out in Flash using a variety of techniques:

1) You can use Flash's BitmapData object to directly shift the hues of the pixels in your item. This is probably the simplest technique but often limits you to simple color transformations.

2) You can pre-render transparent PNG's (or photos, I guess) containing the various textures you would want to show on your object (for instance patterns or textures) and have them dynamically added to your stage at runtime. This, I think, offers the highest fidelity but means you need all of your items rendered upfront.

3) You can create 3D collada files and load them via a library like Papervision3D. Then dynamically change the texture at runtime. This is the most memory intensive technique and tends to result in far worse fidelity, but for that you get a full 3D object that you can view in space.

I'm sure there are other techniques but those are the top 3 I can think of. I hope that helps!